# Should we close the client socket also?

Tags: boost, boost-asio

Please refer to the ASIO examples at: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html

The connection class code is at : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/server/connection.cpp

This class has a stop() function which calls stop on socket that has been created corresponding to a connection request to server (from void server::start_accept())

The client code resides at : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/client/sync_client.cpp

This class also creates a socket at the client end, but this code does not close the socket.

So, there are 2 sockets that are opened: from client to server and vice-a-versa

Questions:

1) Is just closing the socket which the server has opened sufficient or should we also call close on the socket inside the client code ?

2) Should we call shutdown on socket before calling close ?

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to close everything that is closeable.
2. Shutdown before close is redundant unless you have forked a process and inherited the socket.

Comment: Thanks.. One more question.. Is there a way I can cancel a synchronous boost::asio::read operation which is blocking to signify that the client has to shut down.

Comment: @NishantSharma Shutdown the socket *for input*. That will deliver an end of stream to the socket, whereupon Nature should take its course and you will close the socket,

Comment: I had to laugh at "Nature should take its course". Anthropocentrism, naturalism: inevitable crutches of human thinking. +1

Comment: @sehe I certainly don't think they're 'inevitable'. That's the poiint of the joke actually.